# Spark -store JavaDStream<String> rdd to localdisk

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am writing a spark code which is reading from kafka topics.

```
SparkConf sparkConfig =
        new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreaming").setMaster("local[5]");
JavaStreamingContext jsc =
        new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfig,Durations.seconds(5));
final HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(jsc.sc());
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
        KafkaUtils.createStream(jsc,
                                prop.getProperty("zookeeper.connect"),
                                prop.getProperty("group.id"), 
                                topicMap);

JavaDStream<String> lines =
    messages.map(
        new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
```

How do I store these lines rdd in my localdisk.
I was trying something  like below:

```
lines.dstream().saveAsTextFiles
```

But it is not working. Is there any other way to store as textFile to my localdisk.spark

Comment: _it is not working_  is not a good description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs there few options:

- you can use saveAsTextFiles as you mentioned. It should work, so please specify full example and I will try on my own machine. The file name at each batch interval is generated based on `prefix` and `suffix`: "prefix-TIME_IN_MS.suffix".
- you can create any custom logic for saving the events in `foreachRDD()` method
- you can enable write ahead log and all messages are going to be
  stored in the checkpoint directory in a binary format

Comment: where does this file will be placed (exact path).and will this be placed in local or hadoop

Comment: For testing purposes I had set dataStream.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/mydstream", "txt"); so as a  result for each batch interval I see a new directory being created, e.g. mydstream-1464603200000.txt, in which there is a file with the content of the stream during that interval.

Comment: i dont think this will store in local disk..This will store in hdfs.

Comment: It successfully stored that data on my local disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below:

```
lines.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {

            public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/xxx/xxx");
                return null;
            }
        });
```

But this will be stored in hdfs.Not sure if you want to store in hdfs.